# Android Studio - Languages confusion

Tags: android

I am developing app which should support 3 languages: Russian, English, Uzbek. For this purpose, I have created 3 folders in 'res' folder and each has strings.xml file

1. values
2. values-en
3. values-uz

[image]

I would like to have Russian language as default and English and Uzbek languages as optional.

But Android Studio is showing Russian Federation flag for values-en/strings.xml which is very strange.

When I run application, most of time, it works normally. But when system language is English, it starts to behave very strange - switches from English to Russian, then from Russian to English.

Is this Android Studio's bug or I have done something wrong? Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: It will show flags for the languages and it is normal, nothing strange in that

Comment: @Aj27, yeap. For this project, I have this kind of problem. I have never had such problem before

Comment: this is not the problem it is functionality of Android Studio

Comment: @Aj27 , but i think strange thing is that "values-en" shows another country flag.

Comment: @Aj27, yes, values-en showing wrong flag

Comment: tried to delete en/strings.xml and recreate it. but flag is the same - Russian flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change it `values-en` to `values-en-rGB` , it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you I will try this, but what is r means?

Comment: r stands for region

Comment: you can mark this question as accepted if you are clear , so that can help others too. For more information on language and locale you can check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html

Answer (score 0):

also you can change the `locale` in the first run in your app like splash screeen`setLocale("ra",this)` or in your `Application class` if you have.

for example

```
  public void setLocale(String localeCode, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        new PrefManager().setLanguageForDevice(appCompatActivity, localeCode);
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            config.setLocales(new LocaleList(locale));
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
        }          
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I will try this definitely.